# How to use the parrun package

Tags: parallel

The documentation for the `parrun` package claims it can be used to display parallel text. I cannot find any example code showing how to use it and I have failed to create a simple example to test how it work. How do I get this package to display parallel text as it was designed to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You place one text stream in the `fframe` (`f` for "first" perhaps) environment, the other in the `sframe` (`s` for "second"?) environment, and add a `\Place` or `\Place*` command to typeset the contents of the environments, one above the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parrun}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{fframe}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{fframe}
\begin{sframe}
\color{blue}\lipsum[3-4]
\end{sframe}
\Place*
\end{document}
```

[image]