# Remove horizontal line from parrun

Tags: rules, parallel

The `parrun` package places a horizontal line between its two blocks of text (`fframe` and `sframe`).  There’s an example in this answer: [How to use the parrun package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36948/how-to-use-the-parrun-package).

How can I suppress this line? The blank space between the text blocks is sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `parrun.sty`, five internal commands use the `\hrule` primitive. Patching these commands with the help of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to remove `\hrule` seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parrun}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\b@xbalance}{\hrule}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\v@idb@xbalance}{\hrule}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\v@idb@xone}{\hrule}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\v@idb@xtwo}{\hrule}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\splitb@x}{\hrule}{}{}{}% relevant for the MWE
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{fframe}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{fframe}
\begin{sframe}
\color{blue}\lipsum[3-4]
\end{sframe}
\Place*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The last `\patchcmd` is indeed the crucial one.